# How can I correct my code to produce a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a nested dictionary. I have a list of tuples (called 'kinetic_parameters') which looks like this:

```
('New Model','v7','k1',0.1)
('New Model','v8','k2',0.2)
('New Model','v8','k3',0.3)
```

I need the second column to be the outer key and the value to be another dictionary with inner key being the third column and value being the number in the fourth.

I currently have:

```
    for i in kinetic_parameters:
        dict[i[1]]={}
        dict[i[1]][i[2]]=i[3]
```

But this code will not deal with multiple keys in the inner dictionary so I lose some information. Does anybody know how to correct my problem?

I'm using Python 2.7 and I want the output to look like this:

```
{'v7': {'k1': 0.1}, 'v8':{'k2':0.2, 'k3': 0.3}}
```

Comment: How should the new dictionary look like?

Comment: Whats you expected output? and whats your python version?

Comment: What you've shown there is not a list of lists, it's three tuples

Comment: @nu11 and kasra, I have updated the question to include what I want as output. Thanks

Comment: Provide an example of what you would like the output to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code on every loop dictionary is re-initialized. You need to initialize the dictionary first and then add items to it

```
for i in kinetic_parameters:
        d[i[1]]={}
for i in kinetic_parameters:
        d[i[1]][i[2]]=i[3]
```

or check it before initializing

```
for i in kinetic_parameters:
        if d.get(i[1]) is None:
            d[i[1]]={}
        d[i[1]][i[2]]=i[3]
```

Comment: This is not a general way!

Answer (score 3):

Use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), and don't use `dict` as a variable name, since we need it to refer to the dictionary type:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for i in kinetic_parameters:
    d[i[1]][i[2]]=i[3]
```

This will create the dictionaries automatically.

Comment: Not using python type names as variable names is _always_ good advice.

Comment: This will fails for longer lists!

Comment: @Kasra: OP has specified 4-element tuples.  They did not ask for a general solution, nor is it immediately obvious to me that such a solution would even be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Right, if the major ("outer") key has been seen before you should be using the existing dictionary. Or put the other way around: Create an embedded dictionary only if does not exist, then add the value. Here's the logic, using tuple assignment for clarity:

```
nested = dict()
for row in kinetic_parameters:
    _model, outkey, inkey, val = row
    if outkey not in d:
        nested[outkey] = dict()  
    nested[outkey][inkey] = val
```

Or you can skip the existence check by using `defaultdict`, which can create new embedded dicts as needed:

```
from collections import defaultdict
nested = defaultdict(dict)
for row in kinetic_parameters:
    _model, outkey, inkey, val = row
    nested[outkey][inkey] = val
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comprehension to get the last 3 items then use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function to create a nested dictionary :

```
>>> l=[('New Model','v7','k1',0.1),
... ('New Model','v8','k2',0.2),
... ('New Model','v8','k3',0.3)]
>>> 
>>> [reduce(lambda x,y:{y:x},p) for p in [i[1:][::-1] for i in l]]
[{'v7': {'k1': 0.1}}, 
 {'v8': {'k2': 0.2}}, 
 {'v8': {'k3': 0.3}}]
```

This also will works with longer lists :

```
>>> l=[('New Model','v7','k1',0.1,'c','5','r',9),
...  ('New Model','v8','k2',0.2,'d','6'),
...  ('New Model','v8','k3',0.3)]

>>> [reduce(lambda x,y:{y:x},p) for p in [i[1:][::-1] for i in l]]
[{'v7': {'k1': {0.1: {'c': {'5': {'r': 9}}}}}}, 
 {'v8': {'k2': {0.2: {'d': '6'}}}}, 
 {'v8': {'k3': 0.3}}]
```

Edit: If you want a dictionary as the main container you can use a generator expression within `dict` to convert your list to dictionary :

```
>>> g=[reduce(lambda x,y:{y:x},p) for p in [i[1:][::-1] for i in l]]
>>> dict(next(i.iteritems()) for i in g)
{'v8': {'k3': 0.3}, 'v7': {'k1': {0.1: {'c': {'5': {'r': 9}}}}}}
```

Comment: I think op is looking for a dictionary and not list.

Comment: Nested comprehensions + higher-order functions = impossible to read.  OP did not ask for a general solution anyway.

Comment: This answer will remains forever I don't answer for a bounded dimension of time!

Answer (score 1):

```
kinetic_parameters = [('New Model','v7','k1',0.1),
                      ('New Model','v8','k2',0.2),
                      ('New Model','v8','k3',0.3)
                    ]

d = {}
for i in kinetic_parameters:
    if i[1] not in d.keys(): # Check if v7, v8 etc is present.
        d[i[1]] = {}         # Create an empty dict if absent
    d[i[1]][i[2]] = i[3]
print(d)
```

Output is what you expected:

```
{'v7': {'k1': 0.1}, 'v8': {'k3': 0.3, 'k2': 0.2}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, which I believe is easy to understand:

```
import collections

kinetic_parameters = [
    ('New Model','v7','k1',0.1),
    ('New Model','v8','k2',0.2),
    ('New Model','v8','k3',0.3),
]

result = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for _, outter_key, inner_key, inner_value in kinetic_parameters:
    outter_value = {inner_key: inner_value}
    result[outter_key].update(outter_value)
```

In this solution, we use defaultdict for the outer dictionary. The first time we encounter `result[outter_key]`, an empty dictionary will be created and assigned to the value. The next step is to update that value (the inner dictionary).

## Update

If you don't want to use `defaultdict`:

```
result = {}
for _, outter_key, inner_key, inner_value in kinetic_parameters:
    outter_value = {inner_key: inner_value}
    result.setdefault(outter_key, {})
    result[outter_key].update(outter_value)
```

The `setdefault` method create a new dictionary and assign to the outter dictionary only for the first time.